# Spring boot server suddenly shutting down

Tags: spring-boot, server

I have an application written with Spring Boot. The server is running but no one uses it right now. So the server is running and all of a sudden it is shutting down. I really do not know why. There is no error and also the memory seems to be ok. So because I do not see anything in the log except for the message "Server is shutting down" I do not know how to tackle this issue. I built my application with maven command mvn clean package .

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. restart the server.

Comment: What OS is the app running on?

Comment: Of course, I always have to restart the server then it crashes again. I am using linux.

Comment: Have you added the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web` ?

Comment: Sure. My application was running about 10 hours then all of a sudden crashed. No actually it is not crashing, it is just shutting down :) and I do not know why

Comment: How can a server simply shutdown without giving me any error message? In Spring boot can I activate some logging of the framework itself ?

Comment: On my local machine which uses Windows I never have this problem. There are never any shutdowns or crashes. It only happens on the Linux machine where the server finally will be running

Answer (score 0):

I did face similar issue on Solaries box. There were old running processes which were leading into the OS was killing the spring boot service app process. As it was killed by OS (like: `kill -9`) there were no logging in application log file. So Killed all old running processes did solve my issue.